# HTML Form - Multiple Rows (Grid/table input)

Tags: html, spring, thymeleaf, jscript

I'd like to implement the following form in my web app. I am using spring/thymeleaf. Mutiple rows to be submitted as  described below.

The Dispense Details should not have  a limit to the number of items and when I submit all rows in the "dispense details" form must be inserted into the dispense table.

[image: Patient Consult Form]

ER Diagram

[image]

[image]

My first attempt to solve the problem is to add a dispense item one at a time as shown above. On clicking "Add Item" the dispense item is written to the DB and read again  to be displayed under "Dispensed"

I'd  rather have multiple rows of dispense items in a grid which are written  to the Db in one go.

Comment: What did you try? Where is your code? Please refer to [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: the html form for basic inputs are quite easy. I have no idea where to start with grid/table input.